# Open a file in Xbox Music App for Windows 8 with the mouse

Tags: windows-8, xbox-music

In the Xbox Music app you can open a file if you touch-swipe from the bottom up and choose "Open Files" there.

But how can you access this function with just a mouse?

Comment: I've added a request for the upcoming Windows 10 version: https://xboxmusic.uservoice.com/forums/209733-xbox-music-feature-suggestions/suggestions/7112389-let-us-browse-for-files-manually